# Este código debería cargar un valor a una base de datos a través de un archivo php

Tags: c#, c, http, arduino

soy nueva en este foro y agradecería me pudieran ayudar, ya que tengo poca experiencia programando con arduino.

Estoy usando un arduino uno y un shield Ethernet para cargar datos a un servidor. Últimamente he cambiado de usar una base de datos local para usar un servicio de alojamiento web (000webhost) pero no puedo hacer que funcione, no se muestran errores en el IDE de Arduino, solo se detiene en la línea donde dice "MAKING INSERTION".

Todo funcionaba bien cuando tenía la base de datos localmente.

Cuando ingreso la url directamente en el navegador

mythesisinacap.000webhostapp.com/writemydata.php?value=0

funciona bien insertando el valor apropiado en la base de datos ... lo que significa que no hay nada malo con el archivo php en el servidor.

Aquí está mi código del arduino y el código del archivo php que esta en el servidor. Tengo poca experiencia con php.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};

// Enter the IP address for Arduino
// Be careful to use , insetead of . when you enter the address here
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 170);

int vcc = 5; //attach pin 2 to vcc
int trig = 6; // attach pin 3 to Trig
int echo = 7; //attach pin 4 to Echo
int gnd = 8; //attach pin 5 to GND

float cm1;
float cm2;
float cm3;
float cm4;
float cm5;

bool isparked1;
bool isparked2;
bool isparked3;
bool isparked4;
bool isparked5;

long duration;
long duration1;
long duration2;
long duration3;
long duration4;
long duration5;

char server[] = "mythesisinacap.000webhostapp.com";

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
EthernetClient client(80);

void setup() {

pinMode (vcc, OUTPUT);
pinMode (gnd, OUTPUT);
// initialize serial communication:
Serial.begin(9600);

// start the Ethernet connection and the server:
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}
//metodo para calcular los centimetros
float microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
// The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
// The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the
// object we take half of the distance travelled.
return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}

//metodo para ejecutar la medicion
long ejecutarMedicion()
{
pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
pinMode(echo, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);//photocell

return duration;
}


void loop() {

digitalWrite(vcc, HIGH);

Serial.println();
Serial.print("comenzando loop");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("haciendo nueva medicion 1");
Serial.println();

//medicion
duration1 = ejecutarMedicion();
//fin medicion

//calculo en centimetros
cm1 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration1);
//fin calculo de cm
Serial.print("Centimetros 1: ");
Serial.print(cm1);
Serial.println();
//si los centimetros son menos de 100 quiere decir que hay un auto estacionado, si es mayor a 100 el estacionamiento esta desocupado
if (cm1 <= 100)
{
isparked1 = 1;
Serial.print("Estacionado: SI 1");
Serial.println();
}
else if (cm1 > 100)
{
isparked1 = 0;
Serial.print("Estacionado: NO 1");
Serial.println();
}
Serial.print("esperando 2 segundos");
Serial.println();
delay(2000);

Serial.print("haciendo nueva medicion 2");
Serial.println();
duration2 = ejecutarMedicion();

cm2 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration2);
Serial.print("Centimetros 2: ");
Serial.print(cm2);
Serial.println();

if (cm2 <= 100)
{
isparked2 = 1;
Serial.print("Estacionado: SI 2");
Serial.println();
}
else if (cm2 > 100)
{
isparked2 = 0;
Serial.print("Estacionado: NO 2");
Serial.println();
}

if (isparked1 != isparked2)
{
Serial.print("isparked1 es distinto de isparked2");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("esperando 2 segundos");
Serial.println();

delay(2000);

Serial.println();
Serial.print("haciendo nueva medicion 3");
Serial.println();
duration3 = ejecutarMedicion();

cm3 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration3);
Serial.print("Centimetros 3: ");
Serial.print(cm3);
Serial.println();
if (cm3 <= 100)
{
isparked3 = 1;
Serial.print("Estacionado: SI 3");
Serial.println();
}
else if (cm3 > 100)
{
isparked3 = 0;
Serial.print("Estacionado: NO 3");
Serial.println();
}

if (isparked2 == isparked3)
{
Serial.println();
Serial.print("isparked2 == isparked3");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("esperando 2 segundos");
Serial.println();

delay(2000);

Serial.print("haciendo nueva medicion 4");
Serial.println();
duration4 = ejecutarMedicion();

cm4 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration4);
Serial.print("Centimetros 4: ");
Serial.print(cm4);
Serial.println();
if (cm4 <= 100)
{
isparked4 = 1;
Serial.print("Estacionado: SI");
Serial.println();
}
else if (cm4 > 100)
{
isparked4 = 0;

Serial.print("Estacionado: NO");
Serial.println();
}

if (isparked3 == isparked4)
{
Serial.print("isparked3 == isparked4");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("esperando 2 segundos");
Serial.println();

delay(2000);

Serial.print("haciendo nueva medicion 5");
Serial.println();
duration5 = ejecutarMedicion();
cm5 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration5);
Serial.print("Centimetros 5: ");
Serial.print(cm5);
Serial.println();

if (cm5 <= 100)
{
  isparked5 = 1;
  Serial.print("Estacionado: SI");
  Serial.println();
}
else if (cm5 > 100)
{
  isparked5 = 0;
  Serial.print("Estacionado: NO");
  Serial.println();
}

if (isparked2 == isparked3 && isparked3 == isparked4 && isparked4 == isparked5)
{
  Serial.print("Todos los valores de 4 mediciones son iguales");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Conectando...");
  Serial.println();
  if (client.connect(server, 80))
  {
    Serial.print("CONNECTED");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("nuevo valor: ");
    Serial.print(isparked5);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("MAKING INSERTION");
    Serial.println();
    client.print("GET /writemydata.php?value="); // This
    client.print(isparked5);
    if (isparked5==0)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("NO ESTACIONADO");
    }
    else if(isparked5==1)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("SI ESTACIONADO");
    }

    client.println(" HTTP/1.1"); // Part of the GET request
    client.println("Host: mythesisinacap.000webhostapp.com"); // IMPORTANT: If you are using XAMPP you will have to find out the IP address of your computer and put it here (it is explained in previous article). If you have a web page, enter its address (ie.Host: "www.yourwebpage.com")
    client.println("Connection: close"); // Part of the GET request telling the server that we are over transmitting the message
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.stop();    // Closing connection to server
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("no hay conexion");
  }
}
}
}
}
Serial.println();
Serial.print("terminando loop");
Serial.println();
}
```

---

```
<?php 
$dbusername = "username";  // username de la base de datos 
$dbpassword = "pass12345";  // password de la base de datos
$server = "mythesisinacap.000webhostapp.com"; // IMPORTANTE: si se usa XAMPP este valor debe ser "localhost", pero si se usa un website online este debe ser por ejemplo "www.miwebsite.com"
$valor=$_GET["value"];
if($valor==1 || $valor==0)
{
// conectar a la base de datos
$db = new 

PDO('mysql:host=localhost;
dbname=id3463386_estacionamiento2017;charset=utf8mb4', $dbusername, 
$dbpassword);
// ejecutar SQL statement
$db->exec("INSERT INTO id3463386_estacionamiento2017.parking (Estado) VALUES 
('".$valor."')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola notarola, bienvenida a SOes. Te sugiero que que sigas el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el problema sea que al realizar la peticion GET el servidor solamente las permite realizar desde el mismo servidor y no desde otro lugar, para esto deberias agregar la cabecera **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***, para que acepte peticiones desde cualquier dirección, revisa este enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control donde lo explican mejor y como agregar la cabecera en php